# filter pandas columns by list of substrings

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a pandas dataframe with 100+ columns.

```
df.columns = ['casette', 'a true', 'b true', 'blah1', 'blah2', ..... 'a card', 'b card']
```

is there a better way to filter columns based on a list substrings

eg. something along the lines of:

```
df = df[[x for x in df.columns if any(['true', 'cassette', 'card'] not in x)]]
```

instead of:

```
df = df[[x for x in df.columns if 'true' not in x and 'cassette' not in x and 'card' not in x]]
```

to get:

```
df.columns = ['blah1', 'blah2', .....]
```

any tips would be appreciated cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `filter`. Something like:

```
target_list = ['true', 'cassete', 'card']
df.filter(regex="|".join(target_list), axis=1)
```